# How to set routing in serverless framework

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I would like to develop sample apps and its routing by using `serverless-framework`. I send following command

`sls create -t aws-nodejs-typescript -n sample-api-dev`

It generate following directory

```
.
├── src
│   ├── functions               # Lambda configuration and source code folder
│   │   ├── hello
│   │   │   ├── handler.ts      # `Hello` lambda source code
│   │   │   ├── index.ts        # `Hello` lambda Serverless configuration
│   │   │   ├── mock.json       # `Hello` lambda input parameter, if any, for local invocation
│   │   │   └── schema.ts       # `Hello` lambda input event JSON-Schema
│   │   │
│   │   └── index.ts            # Import/export of all lambda configurations
│   │
│   └── libs                    # Lambda shared code
│       └── apiGateway.ts       # API Gateway specific helpers
│       └── handlerResolver.ts  # Sharable library for resolving lambda handlers
│       └── lambda.ts           # Lambda middleware
│
├── package.json
├── serverless.ts               # Serverless service file
├── tsconfig.json               # Typescript compiler configuration
├── tsconfig.paths.json         # Typescript paths
└── webpack.config.js           # Webpack configuration
```

handler.ts

```
import type { ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { formatJSONResponse } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { middyfy } from '@libs/lambda';

import schema from './schema';

const hello: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof schema> = async (event) => {
  return formatJSONResponse({
    message: `Hello ${event.body.name}, welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    event,
  });
};

export const main = middyfy(hello);
```

after that I send following command

`sls local start`

```
MAC0157:$ sls offline start
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Starting Offline at stage dev (us-east-1)

Offline [http for lambda] listening on http://localhost:3002
Function names exposed for local invocation by aws-sdk:
           * hello: pricing-api-dev-dev-hello

   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                                         │
   │   POST | http://localhost:3000/dev/hello                                │
   │   POST | http://localhost:3000/2015-03-31/functions/hello/invocations   │
   │                                                                         │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Server ready: http://localhost:3000
```

My question is

① How can I set routing in each function ?
for example, I would like to add `GET` function in my project.I couldn't find how to set routing in my function.Where is `POST` defined in `hello/handler.ts` ?

② How can I change environment ?
it seems that offline start at stage dev ( us-east-1) , how can I change this stage ?
Are there any setting needed ?

If someone has opinion or materials will you please let me know.
Thanks

Thanks

Comment: with that tempate you used, the events and routes are typically defined in the `index.ts` file which lies in the same folder as the `handler.ts`

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the same function signature for get request.

Just write it this way for get request:

```
const getFunc: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof undefined> = async (event) => {

//Your function logic goes in here

  return formatJSONResponse({
    message: `Hello, welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    
  });
};
```

PS: When initiating a get request, there is no need for a body request property which from my understanding is validated against the schema; so you can just specify undefined for the schema type.